# Using subscripts when defining function

Tags: functions, subscript

My goal is to use subscripts in arguments when defining function.
I tried as below. It is simple addition. But it does not work. It should be 3. What went wrong?

```
In[30]:= Clear[my]

In[28]:= my[Subscript[a, 1] _, Subscript[a, 2] _] := 
 Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2]

In[32]:= my[1, 2]

Out[32]= my[1, 2]
```

Comment: The argument `1` is not of the form `Subscript[a, 1]` and so it does not match the defined pattern.

Comment: What it seems like you're trying to do is name a pattern by the expression `Subscript[a, 1]`. However, notice that putting `_` after the expression does not create a pattern in this case: while `x_ // FullForm` is `Pattern[x, Blank[]]`, `Subscript[a, 1]_ // FullForm` is `Times[Blank[], Subscript[a, 1]]`. It's interpreting juxtaposition as multiplication! And there's a good reason it does this: only symbols (i.e. expressions with head `Symbol`) can be pattern names. If you try forcing it, e.g. `f[Pattern[Subscript[a, 1], Blank[]]] := 5`, you'll get an error saying the pattern name isn't valid.